# ROC specificity in pROC

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I tried to plot ROC curve using pROC packages, the code is as following:

```
install.packages("pROC")
require("pROC")
pMDmedian <- roc(MDmeanall$IDH.type, MDmeanall$MD_median, plot=TRUE, print.thres=TRUE, print.auc=TRUE)
```

The scale of the specificity is defaulted as from 1.5 to -0.5, while what I wish is the scale from 0.0 to 1. The sensitivity also has similar problem. 
 [image]

Comment: A (not optimal) way around this is to just not have your plot window be so wide.

Comment: @Dason it solves my problem now, thanks!

Comment: You might want to communicate this example to the package maintainers. It seems to be undesirable and only they can change it.